# Why is my function never called, even though I explicitly call it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, command-line

So I'm writing this simple CLI tool, and without being too tedious with my code here's essentially what happens:

```
bool IsThing()
{
    // stuff goes here
    return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool IsThing_ = IsThing();
    if ( IsThing_ )
    {
        printf( "foo\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I explicitly try to fail `IsThing()`, even removing literally everything in it except the `return false`. However, every single time, without fail, I'll get a return code of `1`.

To debug, I've put breakpoints inside `IsThing()` and right before calling it in the body of `_tmain()`. The thing that frustrates me the most, is that at the breakpoint inside `IsThing()`, VS will tell me

> No executable code is associated with this line.

When I step through the main function instead, it literally goes to `bool IsThing_ = IsThing();`, then checks the if condition **without ever stepping into the actual function**, and will just skip immediately to what's inside the conditional.

Why is my function call not working?

Comment: The call is probably inlined. Are you compiling in release mode?

Comment: Check for `#define` macros?

Comment: "No executable code is associated with this line" usually means that the project isn't built. Have you made sure to rebuild your project?

Comment: To build off of @Default, put in code that won't compile and verify that fails.

Comment: You need to post the minimum cut down version of your real code that exhibits this behaviour, not just something that paraphrases it.

Comment: @aschepler Yup, checked for those.

Comment: So the only problem here is that you can't make the debugger to stop in the body of `IsThing` function?

Comment: @Default Yes, I've rebuilt my project. Same error.

Comment: @tinman I shit you not, that's literally what I could have and it would give me what I'm describing

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Well debug will work, except why would release not? Isn't my final executable gonna have to be built with release settings anyway? If I run the release build in actual Windows it gives me the same problem as if I'm debugging it in release mode. Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: @RyanGuthrie Done this, and compiler complains. I put `crap goes here` in the main function and it won't build, so I know it's compiling every time.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `IsThing()` definition with just a prototype, `bool IsThing();`?

Comment: @LihO the problem is that `IsThing` doesn't ever seem to run, and that's a problem because the value if `IsThing` is supposed to dictate what happens afterwards but the program will always act like it's a value of `true`, no matter what.

Comment: I never entirely trust what a debugger can or can't figure out.  Are the in-program side effects weird?  e.g. does "foo" get printed even though `IsThing()` is `{ return false; }`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr If I remove the function definition and just make it a prototype, (I run a clean project at this point and try to rebuild) it tells me unresolved external symbol. `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

Comment: @aschepler Yes! That's exactly what happens! The program doesn't seem to give 2 sh*ts about what it actually is.

Comment: OK. Now if you put the `IsThing()` definition in another .cpp file does it work?

Comment: @PhADDinTraining: Step through the code (in debug of course), and right before it calls your function, press CTRL+F11, and it should show the assembly at that spot.  Post the assembly here, and then _while still in the assembly_ try to step into the function.  This will conclusively show if the function is being called at all.  (If it does step in, show that assembly too)

Comment: @PhADDinTraining: And going on a completely off the wall theory, what happens when you add another pair of parenthesis: `IsThing()()`?  Also, make a new project, and put the code in this question there, and debug _that_.  If it works in a different project, that means the error _is not in the code on this page_.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I just tried that. I put `IsThing()` in another .cpp file and just included it in my `main.cpp`, and when I try to rebuild (after a clean of course) it tells me `already defined in isthing.obj`. What env setting did I screw up? lol

ps. First thing I did was check if I double declared it somewhere else. Nope. Ctrl-F showed me nothing I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Sorry everybody, looks like we ran out of time and space. Not gonna take this any further, I'm just gonna make a new project and put these files in before I go home for the day. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're compiling with **Release** configuration that most likely uses [/O1 or /O2 optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx), that is meant to make your code faster and smaller in size. This means that during the compilation this function:

```
bool IsThing() { return false; }
```

is being inlined, which leads to your `main` being equivalent to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool IsThing_ = false;
    if ( IsThing_ )
    {
        printf( "foo\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or even the body of the `if` statement might be omitted, which would lead to just:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

which is also the reason why with **Debug** configuration it works for you. You can try to go to the project properties and under **C/C++ -> Optimization** change *Optimization* option to `Disabled (/Od)` and you should be able to see, that after this change, your breakpoint will work for you :)

Comment: Oh that's beautiful, it worked! But question - had I not known this, and worked completely in debug mode, and just built the thing in release and shipped it, wouldn't it run into errors during actual use? How do I stop this from happening in the future, aside from just disabling optimization every single time?

Comment: @PhADDinTraining: Optimization will just make your code faster and smaller. It will never change the behavior of your code in terms of you being able to see different results (output etc.)... while working on your code, use **Debug** configuration, then when you want to release your application to the world, use **Release**.

Comment: But as we've seen, **Release** will omit important code during optimization. Are you saying debugging in **Release** is different than an actual **Release** build?

Comment: The question states (and verified in comments by @PhADDinTraining) that even with `{ return false; }` it still goes inside the conditional and executes the `printf`. OK, the question as asked was phrased as "why does my function call not work", but I guess the real question should be why does it call `printf` when `IsThing()` returns false. That's why I asked for the real code, sounds like there might be a stray semi-colon at the end of the `if()` line, but it's just a guess without the real code.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool IsThing()
{
    // stuff goes here
    return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool IsThing_ = IsThing();
    if ( IsThing_ )
    {
        printf( "foo\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In release mode, Visual Studio will convert this code to this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, since `IsThing` is no longer needed, no code is generated for it, and thus you can't set breakpoints in it.

Now, it may well be that if you stuff enough code into the function that actually does things (such as file-I/O) and do not hard code a return of `false`, that the compiler will indeed make it into a function that does get called. But compilers these days are very good at eliminating code that doesn't produce anything "meaningful".

I don't think there is any great mystery here - it's just the way compilers work.